# How to capture $false in ValidateScript()

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a function that validates user input and it works as expected. Returns `$true` when correct and Throws an error when not.

Since I would like to return the results (True and False) to be used elsewhere, Is it possible to capture `$false` from `ValidateScript()`?

Tried various operations like if/else and tried searching but did not find anything relevant.

```bsh
function Check-Input-ShareName {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]  
        [ValidateScript({
            if ($_ -match '(?=^[a-zA-Z].{3,30}$)(?![_-].+)(?!.+[_-]$)(?!.*[_-]{2,})[^<>[\]{}|\\\/^~%# :;_,$@%*?\0-\cZ]+$') {
                $true
            } else {
                #Throw "$_ is invalid Share Name." this works and throws error when I uncomment
                $false
            }
        })]
        [string]$ShareName
    )

    Process {
        if ($true) {
            Write-Host 'True'
            return $ShareName
        }

        if ($false) {
            Write-Host 'True'
            return 'invalid'
        }
```

I would like if its false to return false so I can take action on that elsewhere.

Comment: I know i can do it the old fashion way instead of using validatescript, but was just wondering if it was possible. Thanks again.

Comment: If the `ValidateScript()` expression evaluates to `$false` PowerShell will throw a parameter error. The body of the function will not be evaluated in that case. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.